# Derivation of Rotational Motion Equations using Calculus

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, differentiation, integration

How are the equations for rotational motion derived using calculus and the following general equations ?

$$\mathbf{v}(t) = \mathbf{v}_0+\int_{t_0}^t \mathbf{a}(t')dt'$$

$$\mathbf{r}(t) = \mathbf{r}_0+\int_{0}^t \mathbf{v}(t')dt'$$

Let $a(t) = \alpha$

Also, can the polar unit vectors be present throughout the answer so I can see how they effect integration $(\mathbf{r},\theta)$.

Comment: I edited your question to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is the site standard for mathematical expressions.  We actively discourage images of equations.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to get $\phi(t)$ starting from $r(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need those general linear-motion definitions/equations. Rather, you need the equivalent rotational-motion definitions/equations:

$$\mathbf{\omega}(t) = \mathbf{\omega}_0+\int_{t_0}^t \mathbf{\alpha}(t')dt'\\
\mathbf{\theta}(t) = \mathbf{\theta}_0+\int_{0}^t \mathbf{\omega}(t')dt'$$

These are fundamental definitions that just mathematically reflect the fact that *angular* velocity is the change in *angular* position, and *angular* acceleration the change in *angular* velocity, in the same way as in the linear case.

The four usual motion equations are derived by assuming $\alpha$ constant, and in exactly the same way as the linear motion equations are derived. [See a derivation here](https://www.allthatmatters.academy/proof-14-motion-equations/).

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the positions $r(t)$ of any three distinct, non-coplanar points A, B, C in the rigid body. As the object translates and/or rotates, all other points in the rigid body maintain the same positions relative to A, B, C.

If $\alpha$ is a constant then the orientation of the object in 2D is $\theta=\frac12 \alpha t^2$.